# How to find the most repeated value in a array?

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I'm trying to find the most repeated int number of my vector.
Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        temp = vet[i];
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        if(vet[i] == temp){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (most < count){
        most = count;
        elem = vet[i];
    }
}
return elem;
}
```

It's not correct. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can visit each element sequentially and whenever you visit a particular element you add it to another vector and make sure the next time that you check whether the number you want to visit is not already contained in that vector before adding the results. though i don't recommend this for vectors that have alot of elements  as it will be slow.

Comment: I know whats wrong. It doesn't compile!

Comment: For `C` it's a pretty tricky problem, you need either a good algorithm (sort the array first then use a caterpillar method) or a good data structure (a hashtable or dictionary like `Python` ).

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code, then you will quickly find the bug yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem is that your code uses `i` in both the inner and the outer loops. The `most` and `count` variables are uninitialized in the above code, and `count` needs to be reset before starting the inner loop each time.

The method used in this code of iterating over the entire array for each element to count appearances is not very efficient. The efficiency could be improved by starting the inner loop from `i + 1`, instead of from `0`. By doing this, the first frequency count for each element will be correct, though the later counts will be low since the earlier indices will not be visited. But this does not matter, since the first count will have set the `most` variable if possible. The `count` variable can be set to `1` before the inner loop begins, since the `i`th element is the test value, and the inner loop will skip this index. This change will substantially reduce the number of array accesses.

Note that this function will return the value of the *first* element in the array that is also the most frequently appearing.

```
int get_most_common(int vet[], size_t dim)
{
    size_t i, j, count;
    size_t most = 0;
    int temp, elem;

    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        temp = vet[i];
        count = 1;
        for(j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
            if(vet[j] == temp) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (most < count) {
            most = count;
            elem = vet[i];
        }
    }
    return elem;
}
```

Comment: Could the inner loop start at `i + 1` if you set `count = 1;` (because `temp` contains the first value of the set being counted)?  It seems a pity to keep recounting everything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- answer updated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I write This Code do what you need and extra if two numbers have the same repeating times, it returns the Bigger one.

```
     int ReturnMostRepeated(int val[], size_t dim)
{

size_t i,j,count;



int temp=0, temp2;





for(i =0;i<dim;i++)
        {


count = 1;

        for(j=i+1;j<dim;j++)
            {


if(val[j]==val[i])
            {
                count++;
            }

            }


if (count>temp)
        {
            temp = count;
            temp2 = val[i];
        }else if(count == temp) if (val[i]>temp2) temp2 = val[i];

        }

        return temp2;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the brute force method, count the frequency of each element, then find the maximum one.

To implement a full version of such function with efficiency, you will need special data structure such as `hashtable` or `dictionary`.

But the following codes work well if you just need to return the first item that match such condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// returns the first matched most frequent item of a list
// list items of same value must be grouped, for example, a sorted list
// only returns the first matched item
int max_frequent_item_of(int vet[], int dim)
{
  int i = 0;
  // element and its count of current sublist
  int current = vet[0];
  int current_count = 0;
  // most frequent element and its count of the list so far
  int most = vet[0];
  int most_count = 0;
  while (i < dim) {
    // if i-th element still belong to current sublist, run the counter
    if (vet[i] == current) {
      current_count += 1;
      i += 1;
    }
    // otherwise, the current sublist just ended
    else {
      // update the most frequent element
      if (current_count > most_count) {
        most = current;
        most_count = current_count;
      }
      // reset current sublist
      current = vet[i];
      current_count = 1;
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  printf("most frequent item %d, count %d\n", most, most_count);
  return most;
}

int main(void)
{
  // vet must be in order, sort with `qsort` if necessary
  int vet[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 9};
  int size = 10;
  int n;
  printf("list: ");
  for (n = 0 ; n < size; n++)
    {
      printf("%d ", vet[n]);
    }
  printf("\n");
  max_frequent_item_of(vet, size);
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
list: 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 8 9 9
most frequent item 4, count 3
```

Comment: With an O(N log N) sort and this being O(N), if the array can be ordered, this gives O(N log N) performance overall, and O(N) on the searching.  Either is better than O(N^2) for large enough N.